# 3 modules, but 1 installer

Tags: c#, winforms, merge, wix, installation

In our current project, we have a product consisting of 3 modules. We would like to deliver only one installer, which will allow the user to select which module(s) to (un)install.

I've got 2 plans:

- to make one .exe file in C# .net 4.0 windows forms, which will invite the user to select which modules to (un)install. Each module will be coded in Wix. So when the user selects a module to install, it will launch the corresponding msi. But we want to deliver only one installer, not 3.
- to make one msi with Wix, but I want to enter install/uninstall mode only when the user selects "install module x" or "uninstall module x" pushbutton respectively.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using **single installer with few [Features](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html)** (take a look [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/08/23/from-msi-to-wix-part-4-features-and-components.aspx) and to the [WIX documentation](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/first-steps) to read about Features, components and how to organize them). Every Feature can be installed, or removed separately in the "Change" mode of installation. You should use [FeatureTree](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_featuretree.html) dialog set or [another set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html) that contains feature selection dialog

Comment: Thanks, very simple solution !